# $N$ powers of a time-ordered integral?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Suppose we have some $t$-dependent Hermitian Hamiltonian operator $H(t)$ and we build the time-ordered evolution operator
$$
U(t,t_0) := T\exp\left\{ - i \int_{t_0}^t dt' \; H(t') \right\} \ .
$$
Is there a way in which the operator $U(t,t_0)^{N}$ can be simplified?

For comparison, if $H(t) = H$ is time-independent then $U(t,t_0) = e^{- i (t-t_0)H}$ and it follows that $U(t,t_0)^N  = e^{- i N (t-t_0) H}$.

Can one similarly put the $N$ in the power of the time-ordered integral?

EDIT: I don't think it is as simple as putting the $N$ in the time-ordered product, meaning $$U(t,t_0)^N \neq T\exp\left\{ - N i \int_{t_0}^t dt' \; H(t') \right\}.$$

Comment: If $H(t)$ is time-dependent, then $U(t,t_0)$ evolves a state from one specific time $t_0$ to another specific time $t$. In what context would you need to do this $N$ times? It's well-posed mathematically, but where do you want to use it? I'm asking because the meaning of "simplified" depends on where you want to use it.

Comment: @Chiral_Anomaly I have a somewhat specific calculation in which I need to evaluate the expectation value of U(t,t_0)^n in a particular state. It seems like it should be expressible in terms of a time-ordered exponential,but I am not sure

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: $U(t,t_0)^k$ is not itself a time-ordered expression, so I don't think it's necessarily possible to write it as a single time-ordered expression.

Detail:

The time-ordered integral for $U(t, t_0)$ is this:
$$
U(t,t_0) = T\exp\left\{-i\int_{t_0}^t dt' H(t')\right\} = \lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=0}^{N-1}\exp\left\{-i H\left(t_0 + \frac{n}{N}(t - t_0)\right)\frac{t-t_0}{N}\right\}
$$
(sorry to use $N$ differently than you did, but it's the clearest I can make it). It's a clunky formula, but basically you're splitting the integral into a sum (in time order) and then splitting the exponential into a product (in time order), all within a limit. This is backward from what actually happens, you really start with the product, and then you can't condense it into a single exponential because $H(t_1)$ and $H(t_2)$ do not in general commute. So we have this notation for the limit of the product.

In order to raise $U(t,t_0)$ to some power, you must use the right hand side of the above equation:
$$
U(t, t_0)^k = \left(\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=0}^{N-1}\exp\left\{-i H\left(t_0 + \frac{n}{N}(t - t_0)\right)\frac{t-t_0}{N}\right\}\right)^k.
$$
This is not very condensed, but you might notice that this expression is *not time ordered*; it goes like this:
$$
\exp\left\{-i H\left(t-dt\right)\frac{t-t_0}{N}\right\}\bigg(\cdots\bigg)\exp\left\{-i H\left(t_0\right)\frac{t-t_0}{N}\right\}\exp\left\{-i H\left(t - dt\right)\frac{t-t_0}{N}\right\}\cdots
$$
so not all of the $H(t)$s are in order. Since the general expression isn't time-ordered, I don't think it's necessarily possible to put write it as a single time-ordered expression.